# Open MATLAB script with PHP

Tags: php, string, matlab

I need to run a MATLAB script from PHP file.

This is what I tried, which doesn't work:

```
$cmd = '/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nosplash - nodesktop -r "run('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/files/appResponse.m')" ';
shell_exec($cmd);
exit;
```

But this code works:

```
$cmd = '/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nosplash - nodesktop -r ';
shell_exec($cmd);
exit;
```

I couldn't figure out how to fix the first command to run the `.m` script file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check your quotes, you'll see a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly escape the quotes. Notice the backslashes:

```
$cmd = '/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nosplash - nodesktop -r "run(\'/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/files/appResponse.m\')"';
shell_exec($cmd);
exit;
```

Now the `$cmd` variable contains a valid path to the Matlab executable, with proper arguments as far as PHP is concerned:

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nosplash - nodesktop -r "run('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/files/appResponse.m')"
```

Comment: no man , $cmd = "/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r 'run '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/files/appResponse.m'' ";    is the correct one.

Comment: $cmd = "/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/bin/matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r 'run '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/files/appResponse.m' ' ";

Comment: I don't think so. It's an invalid string. Open a terminal, issue `php -a` and try it for yourself.